# htaccess redirect missing bundle.*.js version to bundle.js file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am using htaccess redirect to send missing assets to Apache 404 for optimization.

```
# BEGIN Apache 404 for broken resouces
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|icns|swf|bmp|css|js)$ - [nocase,redirect=404,last]
# END Apache 404 for broken resouces
```

Although this should also serve the last file if file is missing I'd like to update this with the following to avoid caching issues:

**- if bundle.[version].js or bundle.[version].css is missing serve bundle.js or bundle.css instead. Currently unable to achieve this. Any ideas to improve this?**

Comment: bundle.*.js or bundle.*.css is missing

Comment: Just add a RewriteRule that matches those specific patterns, and redirects to the respective version without a version number in it - and preceed it with a RewriteCond again, exactly the same as you already have, that checks if what was requested is not an existing file?

Comment: Is `[version]` just a numeric string? Or what characters can this part contain? Are `bundle.js` and `bundle.css` guaranteed to always exists? "Currently unable to achieve this." - What did you try?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, i.e bundle.c22cc05.js. bundle.js / .css always exist but I need a fallback for users who haven't visited the site for over a month or so and have the old bundle versioning solution cached (I moved versioning to query parameter). I tried using i.e RewriteRule bundle.*.css bundle.css$1 [L] but this just 404's for bundle.css as well.

Comment: What are the full URL-paths to `bundle.[version].js`, `bundle.[version].css`, `bundle.js` and `bundle.css`?

Comment: /wp-content/themes/custom-theme/build/bundle.[version].css & /wp-content/themes/custom-theme/build/build.css & /wp-content/themes/custom-theme/build/bundle.[version].js & /wp-content/themes/custom-theme/build/build.js @MrWhite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> serve `bundle.js` or `bundle.css` instead.

Just to note, in your comment, you wrote this as `build.js` and `build.css` respectively?

You could either, create another `.htaccess` file in the `/wp-content/themes/custom-theme/build` subdirectory (which contains both the `.js` and `.css` files) with the following directives:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^bundle\.\w+\.(js|css)$ bundle.$1 [L]
```

OR, add the following directives to the top of the root `.htaccess` *before* your existing directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/bundle\.\w+\.(js|css)$ $1/bundle.$2 [L]
```

The first option is marginally more efficient as it completely overrides the directives in the parent `.htaccess` file and is only processed on the necessary requests. However, the second option is perhaps easier to maintain as it keeps all your directives in one place.

Comment: Great work, thanks for the effort! Correct about bundle.js / bundle.css respectively